# ReactJS + Firebase Email Sending

Tags: reactjs, firebase, email

simple way to send multiple emails at a time using reactJS and Firebase..?

Am getting simple fuction using sendmail npm but that also is not working..

I dont want to use node.js or express..

Simple email sending function using redux firebase

Comment: are you using a `@gmail.com` address to send emails?

Comment: Yes i want to use @gmail.com

Comment: Are you using the `node mailer` module

Comment: Sorry for late.. Yes ive used node module

Comment: node mailer doesn't support gmail address out of the box. You need to add extra configurations

Comment: any suggestions..? @IshanJoshi I havent found any related solutions.